# SiteMapNode OnClick Event MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvcsitemapprovider

Currently using MVC 5 and C#. I am trying to trigger a popup (javascript) by clicking a button tied to a sitemapnode which lives in my navigation menu bar. I do not want to actually navigate away from the current page, which is the problem because the sitemapnode requires a "url" attribute and/or an "action" attribute.

Basically I want the sitemapnode to behave like a stupid button with an Onclick attribute that fires some javascript. Without leaving the page.

The clearest answer that I've found is:

[jquery dialog from sitemapnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016930/jquery-dialog-from-sitemapnode)

but it uses WebForms and so the solution is not easily translatable. I have found ZERO answers of how to do this in MVC.

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: Solution hack: Use the following attributes in the sitemapnode which inadvertently creates a class which I can use for a click event and simultaneously stops the URL from going anywhere: `url="#" imageUrl="glyphicon glyphicon-heart makedonation"`.

And the selector: `$donateref = $('.makedonation').parent();

$donateref.click(function (event) {` etc...

Comment: Please post a code example of what you are trying to achieve. It is unclear why you would need the button to relate to a node since it is 1) not navigating anywhere and 2) you can add a button to the markup that is generated by adding it to the templates in the  `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` folder (and if necessary, you can use [custom attributes](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Custom-Attributes-on-a-Node) to turn the button on or off or call a specific JavaScript function based on the node configuration).

Comment: If I had a code example of what I wanted to achieve then I would not be asking this question. Besides, I already answered my own question in the comment before your comment.